# How do I set up the React live server in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I was working on a react app but when I changed the script file, the liveserver doesn't show me updates that I make to the jsx file. Only updates in the html file are shown. I have linked the script file in the html with the specific file directory. What seems to be the problem?

JS code:

```
// 
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  return <h1>Hello, World!</h1>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have initialized before I installed the react and react-dom packages. But still no updates on live server.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, did you use `create-react-app` to create this project.

Comment: No, I just created a file, navigated to that file in vs, and installed the react package.

Comment: It doesn't work like that,  to run React, you need to set up React and install all required packages.

The fastest way to get started with React is to use vite: https://vitejs.dev/guide/.

After installing Vite and setting up a new react project, you can run the command `npm run dev` to start the react project.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

To start a Node.js project, you need to have the "node_modules" directory, which contains all the dependencies required for your project. If you haven't installed the dependencies yet, you can do so by running the following command in the project folder:

```
npm install
```

Once the dependencies are installed, you can start your Node.js project by running the command:

```
npm start
```

This command will execute the "start" script defined in the "package.json" file, which typically runs your application. Make sure you have a valid "start" script defined in the "package.json" file.

If you already have the "node_modules" directory and want to start your project, you can directly run the "npm start" command without the need to install the dependencies again.

Please note that you need to have Node.js and npm (Node Package Manager) installed on your system to run these commands.